# How to create multidimensional array of time series

Tags: python

I need to store in one data structure the results of several experiments. The experiments depends on 4 parameters, let's say p1, p2, p3, p4.  The result of these experiments are five measurements over time, that is, five arrays of size N_E: m1, m2, m3, m4, m5. The duration of each experiment is not constant, so N_E depends on p1, p2, p3 and p4.

I tried creating a 4-dimensional ndarray in numpy and a 4 dimensional dataframe in pandas but it doesn't work because N_E is not constant.

Is it possible to summarize this data in python? So far, we have one file per set of parameters, for instance results_p1_p2_p3_p4.npz and inside each file there is a dataframe with the five arrays m1-m5.

Many thanks in advance!
Ken

Edit: Thanks for your comments!

I uploaded a sample on my data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bm6fiwzedytaedj/Example_Data.zip. It's only 5 files but it should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: Can you supply a sample input file for testing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to be a design resource, but I think your question is specific enough to warrant inclusion as a specific programming problem.

Comment: Please supply sample input, as do more to describe your future use.  The confusing part for me is that you seem to ask for a way to store the data in an organized fashion (i.e. "data base", in its most general sense), but then you ask whether it's possible to *summarize* that data -- and you haven't described the summary you want or the eventual use cases thereof.

Comment: Your sample data could be smaller: say, three parameters and two arrays of results.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I uploaded some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have trouble with this scenerio. My goto solution to this is to make a 2d pandas dataframe with a file_id columns along with your other measurements (e.g. file_id, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5). then when I need to process them within file I will do:

```
for file_id, file_df in df.groupby('file_id'):
      //process here
```

Where file_df would contain only the dataframe for one file per loop.

Although this feels inefficient for me since file_id column would be redundant value within rows of one file I don't know of a specific data structure that deals with non-uniformed length time series data.